# Loop a video mask in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video

Say I have some footage that is 30 frames long, and I want to to apply a mask to it via mix nodes that is 3 frames long. I need it to loop 10 times to cover all my frames. How do I do this in the compositor? If it's not possible in the compositor, can it be done in the sequence editor?

Comment: What is your exact intention of using a mask? A mask of 3 frames repeated 10 times doesn't make much sense to me... Or are this just example lengthes?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_06cWLUZ_Bg&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=22

Comment: It's just example lengths.

Comment: Export your mask as a black and white image sequence. Re-import it as as an image sequence in the compositor and enable the **Cyclic** option.

Comment: Yo Cegaton, you should put that answer into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your setup on the compositor is like this:

[image]

Unplug the input from the mix node and make the colors black and white and render the mask as an image sequence.

[image]

And import them as an image sequence node:

[image]

And use the sequence instead of the mask node.

[image]

Make sure the cyclic and auto refresh options are enabled.

[image]

The mask will be used in an endless cycle:

[image]

The main disadvantage of this solution is that if you need to make changes on the mask's shape you have to re-export/re-load the images.

Answer (score 2):

A labor intensive solution would be to copy the keyframes for the mask.

Go to the Dope Sheet window and enable Mask Mode.

Then select the keyframes for the mask (press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all), duplicate them (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and move them over on the time line (press <kbd>G</kbd> to move), duplicate again as needed to get as many iterations of the mask you need.

[image]

Even tough this solution seems a bit more tedious, editing and re-shaping the masks is quite easy. Also if you need to change the order in which the mask changes shape you just need to re-order the key frames.